# Backup torrents for clean install

Tags: installation, backup, transmission

Tomorrow I'm going to do a clean install of Ubuntu 12.10, since I've been playing with some internals and now my system is quite messy. Everything is prepared, my files backed up and I've already made a list with the programs I'm going to need, etc. But there's still one thing missing: my torrents.

I use Transmission and, like everyone should, I like to keep my seeding my files after download. I've set Transmission to delete the .torrent files after I start to download. I actually don't know if the torrents' data is stored at the home directory or not.

1) Is it stored on the home folder? (If it is, it's not going to be a problem since I use a separate partition for the home folder)

2) If it's not, is there a way to backup the torrents' info, so I can continue seeding after my clean install?

Comment: Check your `config/transmission/torrents` inside your home folder. Your .torrent files should be there.

Comment: Yes they are! Thanks! All magnets are stored as ordinary .torrents there, also! Could you please post this as an answer?

Comment: Done! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Active torrents should be in `.config/transmission/torrents` inside your home folder. Since you have `/home` on a seprate partition, no backup is needed.