# how to import magnet links, torrent files and downloads?

Tags: system-installation, backup, file-sharing, bittorrent, transmission

Can transmission "import" magnet links and files?  How would those magnet links get backed up?  The .torrent files and downloads are [easy](https://askubuntu.com/q/1166980/45156) enough to [backup](https://askubuntu.com/q/202202/45156).

What I have in mind is to put the downloads and torrent files onto an external drive.  But what is the import procedure?

Comment: I thought the point of magnet links was their was no 'direct' or saved file. They were a 'link' (URI) that was supposed to be transferred directly from the browser to torrent software, not using a file on the file-system.  Where your 'torrent' software downloads & saves the later downloaded file is controlled by your chosen software (configuration).

Comment: The link *seems* to be saved, but I'm not sure where or how.  Right clicking in transmission gives an option to see the URI, and, transmission-server, again, *seems* to have a CLI interface to get the URI's.

Comment: I suspect it's saved in a temporary location that doesn't live past reboot/shutdown.  I would explore by grabbing magets, get the "link" detail you saw and `fgrep` to find it. I suspect the location could vary on kernel/software-stack version but i'm only guessing sorry.  I know qtransmission can use magnet links as I tested it only weeks ago but I was only testing the mechanism worked (on a new install); didn't create/understand the code behind it sorry.  If I come across the details of my testing [phab] & refresh my knowledge I'll return with more.